# TFS2010 Custom Build Activity : to Merge branches

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I'm working on customizing our build activity. I'd like to have your help for an issue.

Following is our version control hierarchy.

```
Main
 |- Dev
 |- QA
```

we are working on Dev branch and while taking the build we need to merge Dev branch to Main then to QA.
 Main is the root branch as you might know.

In our build template, I've added two custom activities to merge one from Dev to Main and another one to merge from Main to QA. Following is the code for the custom activity.

```
protected override string Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
   string lstrStatus = string.Empty;

   string lstrSourceBranchPath = context.GetValue(this.SourceBranchPath);
   string lstrTargetBranchPath = context.GetValue(this.TargetBranchPath);

   // Obtain the runtime value of the input arguments
   Workspace workspace = context.GetValue(this.Workspace);

   GetStatus status = workspace.Merge(lstrSourceBranchPath,
             lstrTargetBranchPath,
             null,
             null,
             LockLevel.None,
             RecursionType.Full,
             MergeOptions.None);

   // resolve the conflicts, if any

   if (status.NumConflicts > 0)
   {
      Conflict[] conflicts = workspace.QueryConflicts(new string[]
                             { lstrTargetBranchPath }, true);

      foreach (Conflict conflict in conflicts)
      {
         conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptTheirs;
         workspace.ResolveConflict(conflict);
      }
   }

   // checkin the changes
   PendingChange[] pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
   if (pendingChanges != null && pendingChanges.Length > 0)
   {
      workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, "Merged by MERGE BRANCHES activity");
   }
   return lstrStatus;
}
```

Problem is, merging happens perfectly in the server. But, it's not getting reflected in the local folder. I tried to add `SyncWorkspace activity` after each `Merge custom activity`. Still not working.

Comment: What type of build are you invoking? (Gated, CI, Rolling, Manual)

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your response.
I'm running the manual build.

Comment: What about a get latest command?

Comment: How about using different workspaces?

Comment: Hi Edward, I tried to use "workspace.Get(VersionSpec.Latest, GetOptions.GetAll);" as the last line of my merging activity. but, it did not help.

Comment: Hi John, you mean remote workspaces? If so, workspace.Merge says remote workspace cannot be used. And, I'd like to set up build service and all build related stuffs in one machine.

Comment: A merge with automated conflict resolution on build seems a bit risky to me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess was that a `SyncWorkspace` should be the only thing to do.
You could try doing a `RevertWorkspace` before that.

**EDIT**
After you now stated that even this wouldn't work, I would generate a bug against MS at least to get an official answer.
In the meanwhile you can try with the following method, which I absolutely see as an overkill: Once you have checked in, redo all the steps within sequence `Initialize Workspace`.

If even that doesn't work I'd consider two different builds, one that does your merge & one that does the actual build. You can then organize a scheme where your first build, once it's done, triggers the second one. [Here](http://jpadda.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/tfs-2010-queue-new-build-workflow-activity/) is a good resource for that.

Comment: Hi, as you suggested I added RevertWorkspace then SyncWorkspace activities after the merging activity. But, it did not help though.

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion and efforts. Could you please explain what do you mean by this ".........In the meanwhile you can try with the following method, which I absolutely see as an overkill: One you have checked in, redo all the steps within sequence Initialize Workspace. "? What I do now is, inside a sequence, get workspace, sync workspace and merge branches. Could you please explain?

Comment: `Initialize Workspace` also contains steps that clear your last workspace. So you could run your build up to the point where you merge & checkin your merge, then initialize again your workspace & get the latest of all your source code. This should contain your checkins. I consider this an overkill, still it should work.